# Как вычислить, кто вешает сервер?

Tags: linux, сервер, debian

Около недели назад яндекс вебмастер начал присылать уведомления о том, что время ответа всех сайтов на сервере периодически вырастает до 30-60 сек (полный ахтунг). Техподдержка дала ответ, что с 22 июня нагрузка на сервер возросла, и даже приложила скрин (см. ниже). Они посетовали на активность вредоносных ботов, коих и заблокировали. Однако проблема не исчезла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как бы мне теперь вычислить подонка, который вешает мои сайты? Запускал atop, но момента, когда виснет сервер, поймать не смог. Может быть, где-то в логах можно найти пиковые нагрузки и узнать, кто в этом виноват? Доступ по ssh имеется.

Заранее спасибо!

**Upd 07.07.2020**

По какой-то причине atop не хочет признаваться, кто же кушает процессорное время. То, что нагружается процессор, видно по этому скрину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там еще память регулярно немного скачет, но это я знаю, что такое. А вот пиковые нагрузки процессора для меня остаются загадкой.

В atop установил интервал в 60 секунд, однако он вообще не показывает мне таких скачков. Например, загрузка процессора составляла 100% в 4:37 утра. Прикладываю лог atop'a на этот момент - у него все хорошо, проц простаивает :-/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А посещаемость сайта по логам вебсервера какая? Там всё спокойно?

Comment: Да, там все тихо. Посещаемость пока что минимальная, еще не восстановилась после пандемии.

Comment: atop в realtime запускал или просматривал сохранённые журналы? стандартное время слепков - 10 минут, что может быть очень много. уменьши его до минуты, и потом поминутно просматривай какой процесс утилизирует сервер. при веб нагрузке - в топе может быть веб сервер, хотя на самом деле это следствие и нужно смотреть следующий за ним. ещё полезен iotop - смотреть в момент повышенной нагрузки

Answer (score 3):

Однозначно стоит копать логи, можно параллельно гуглить, как защищаться от [DDoS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0). Не факт, что это именно DDoS, но методики решения могут быть схожими.

Для начала нужно определить, какой из сервисов дает высокую нагрузку, это внезапно может оказаться вообще не веб-сервер, а например DNS сервер, или еще что-то, к чему есть доступ извне.

Еще определите, что является причиной отказа: процессор, память, дисковая система, что-то еще?

Когда обнаружите проблемный сервис и причину отказа, смотрите в его логи глубже, если это веб-сервер, то какая его часть? Например, если nginx, то нагружать может php-fpm, или сам nginx. Допишите отслеживающих правил в фаервол, смотрите, что именно генерит трафик, какого он типа, какие это запросы по каком протоколу.

И вот тогда можно уже будет целенаправленно раздавать баны.

Comment: Причину отказа выяснил - процессор. Подскажите, как теперь можно определить, кто именно его вешает? Atop не помог (или руки кривые). Первый свой пост я дополнил.

Comment: @Anton То что нагрузка 0% - это явно что-то не так с логированием, не может быть так, что один монитор показывает 100%, а второй 0% на один и тот же момент времени. Здесь я вам не особо помощник, так как я больше по FreeBSD, и все мои атаки обычно отражались получением списка генерящих трафик IP из логов nginx, и добавлением бана в ipfw. Что там в access/error логах апача?

Comment: Разозлился, запустил atop в реалтайме с интервалом в 1 секунду. Долго ждать не пришлось, уже через несколько минут спалился php. Виновник найден, можно ли теперь как-то понять, чем же он бывает так занят?

Comment: @Anton ну, вам виднее, какие у вас скрипты выполняются и по каким запросам извне. Опять же, смотрите логи апача, апач же проксирует запросы в PHP, значит все должно быть в логах. Если же нет, то логирование все равно можно включить на стороне PHP. Инструкций и гайдов по этим вопросам полно.

Answer (score 0):

Пишем скрипт, который чекает нагрузку на сервере и делает снапшоты top-a при высокой нагрузке

```
#!/bin/bash

avg=$(cat /proc/loadavg | awk -F "." '{print $1}')

if [ "$avg" -gt 10 ]
  then
    top -b -n 1 >> /tmp/htop_snapshot_full.log && cat /tmp/full_htop_snapshot.log | awk '$9 > 1' >  /tmp/htop_snapshot_filtred.log
fi
```

Заталкиваем его в крон и ставим выполнение каждую минуту(ну или по вашему усмотрению). В моем примере есть подобие фильтрации, его можно убрать.

```
*/1 * * * * /home/top_snapshot.sh
```

Анализируем лог, что конкретно грузит. Далее, соответственно, идем анализировать логи программ, которые находились под нагрузкой.

Если у вас есть финансовые мощи, рекомендую затолкать ваш трафик за какой нибудь cloudflare.

Возможно стоит проверить настройку вашего фаервола на наличие "лишних" разрешений.